# Dynamically pass Type to Method<T>

Tags: linq, entity-framework, generics, parameter-passing, dynamically-generated

I've a method , that retrieves to me some data according to some type I passed in parameter, like this :

```
    protected void FillList<TEntity>()
    {
        doWorkForTEntity();
    }
```

I Need to dynamically call this method :

```
            Type[] entities = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(User)).GetTypes();
            Type currentEntity = (from entity in entities
                                  where entity.Name.Equals(this.targetEntity)
                                  select entity).FirstOrDefault();
            FillList<currentEntity>();
```

I got this error :

> The type or namespace name 'currentEntity' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I've tried an intermediate object type, no success

Any Idea please ?

Comment: This example code smells very odd, how do you expect to "do work for a generic type" exactly? (or is this just a simplified example..?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is no information about entity type in compile time, you need to construct and call appropriate method by reflection:

```
Type[] entities = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(User)).GetTypes();
Type currentEntity = (from entity in entities
                      where entity.Name.Equals(this.targetEntity)
                      select entity).FirstOrDefault();     
var method = this.GetType().GetMethod("FillList",  BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
                           .MakeGenericMethod(currentEntity);
method.Invoke(this, new object[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do that with reflection as well, so it won't fail in compile time (compiler checks):

**Generic class:**

```
Type[] entities = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(User)).GetTypes();
Type currentEntity = (from entity in entities
                           where entity.Name.Equals(this.targetEntity)
                           select entity).FirstOrDefault();
 Type fillListType= typeof(FillList<>);
 Type constructedGenericClass = fillListType.MakeGenericType(currentEntity);
 object myList = Activator.CreateInstance(constructedGenericClass );
```

**Generic Method:**

```
Type[] entities = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(User)).GetTypes();
Type currentEntity = (from entity in entities
                           where entity.Name.Equals(this.targetEntity)
                           select entity).FirstOrDefault();
MethodInfo methodinfo = this.GetType().GetMethod("FillList");
MethodInfo genericMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(currentEntity);
genericMethod.Invoke(this, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Type parameters must be specified at compile time and can´t be assigned at runtime like in your example. You get the error message because there´s no Type called `currentEntiry` since it´s just a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Change your method to take an instance of the Type TEntity:

```
protected void FillList<TEntity>(TEntity instance)
{
    doWorkForTEntity();
}
```

Create a dynamic instance from the Type name and then call the modified method:

```
dynamic instance = Activator.CreateInstance(this.targetEntity);
FillList(instance);
```

The dynamic type is basically doing what the other answers have shown you - but IMHO this code is neater and clearer in its intent.